# AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'check_password' error in Django?

Tags: django, django-authentication

I have a custom model with which I am trying to authenticate:

```
class User(models.Model):
    #id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    #identifier = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True, db_index=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=90, unique=True, db_index=True)
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    update_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    external = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    deleted = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    purged = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    form_values_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    disk_usage = models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=16, decimal_places=0, blank=True)
    #last_login = models.DateTimeField()

    objects = UserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    #check_password(password)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'galaxy_user'
```

I have mentioned this in `settings.

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'fileupload.user'

```
 #views.py
        def login_backend(request):
            if request.method == 'POST':
                username = request.POST['username']
                password = request.POST['password']
                user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
                if user is not None:
                    login(request, user)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/overview/')
                else:
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/login_backend/')
            else:
                return render_to_response('login_backend.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

However I am getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'check_password' error
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why you override User model? If you want to add other field information for User just extend it. Don't override it.

Comment: This is completely a new model, I am just naming it as User.

Comment: Yeah I know, but don't use User model because django use that as default model. You encountered check_password error because the real User model has a built-in function for that but your customize User model, don't have that.

Comment: Renaming the model to GalaxyUser didn't help :(

Comment: It's re-producing the same error.

Comment: did you delete your database and sync it again?

Comment: Yes just did, still the same error!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As described in the [custom user documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model), your User model must inherit from `django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser`, which adds all the relevant methods.

Comment: I did that but I got this error:FieldError: Local field 'password' in class 'User' clashes with field of similar name from base class 'AbstractBaseUser'
After that I commented the password field but the correct username and password is authenticated false.

Answer (score 0):

In [the documentation for Django 1.5](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser) (which is the first one with AUTH_USER_MODEL) shows the method the alternative User model must have, and one of them is check_password. So, IMO, you have two ways for solving your issue.

1. Substitute the User model properly providing all required methods.
2. Forget about substituting the User model and [just write a custom AUTH BACKEND](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend) without including "AUTH_USER_MODEL"

Comment: How can I provide all the required methods?

Comment: Just add all methods defined in [AbstractBaseUser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser)

Comment: That's what I want to do but add where?

Comment: To the user model you are writing

Answer (score 0):

Get the [Django 1.5 RC](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/). And follow [these instructions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model) on writing a custom User class.

Comment: I am using the Django 1.5 RC. I am following the instruction. Find out I need to add check_password method but add where?

Comment: Your `User` model is not derived from `AbstractBaseUser` which is why it doesn't have the `check_password` method. You should have something like `class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):`

Comment: Also, don't forget to mention in the `settings.py` the following line: `AUTH_USER_MODEL = '<your_app>.<your_model>'`

Comment: I did that but I got this error:FieldError: Local field 'password' in class 'User' clashes with field of similar name from base class 'AbstractBaseUser' After that I commented the password field but the correct username and password is authenticated false

Comment: That is because the `AbstractBaseUser` class has already defined it. You need only to add your custom fields that are not defined in `AbstractBaseUser`. Alternatively you can inherit from `AbstractUser` which offers even more advanced functionality (usernames, permissions, etc). I suggest you have a look at the source ($PATH_TO_DJANGO_SOURCE/django/contrib/auth/models.py)

Answer (score 0):

Add from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password after get_user_model